# Wi-Fi connection to Mac Mini

Tags: wifi

I am thinking of purchasing a Mac Mini. I currently have a Wi-Fi network in my home using a WebCaster 3100SV router (Japan-NTT). Will I have a problem connecting to my existing Wi-Fi connection for my Windows based Pc's?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your router broadcasts 802.11n or 802.11g WiFi, you should be ok.

Comment: What if it doesn't? You might want to give a little more details here...